# image decoding in asp

Tags: java, asp-classic, encoder, decoder

HI can any body tell me how to decode a base64 string in asp classic encoded by java from an image

Comment: why this question is tagged with `JAVA`?

Comment: because the string is decoded by java so may be any java person may also help

Comment: @user571616 In the text you say it's encoded by Java; which is it? In any case, when I search Google there's a *lot* of results--perhaps if you tried implementing one of those and asked a more-specific question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [base64 image decoder for ASP classic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920416/base64-image-decoder-for-asp-classic)

Answer (score 0):

Pass the base64 string into decodeBase64() function, as below and pass file name and returned value into writeBytes procedure, image will create on the file system

```
private function decodeBase64(base64)
        dim DM, EL
        Set DM = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
        ' Create temporary node with Base64 data type
        Set EL = DM.createElement("tmp")
        EL.DataType = "bin.base64"
        ' Set encoded String, get bytes
        EL.Text = base64
        decodeBase64 = EL.NodeTypedValue
    end function


private Sub writeBytes(file, bytes)

        Dim binaryStream
        Const TypeBinary = 1, ForWriting = 2
        Set binaryStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        binaryStream.Type = TypeBinary
        'Open the stream and write binary data
        binaryStream.Open
        binaryStream.Write bytes
        'Save binary data to disk
        binaryStream.SaveToFile file, ForWriting
End Sub
```