# How to save canvas image using classic ASP?

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, base64, html5-canvas

I'm a bit stuck here. I know that I can use the canvas.toDataURL to produce a base64 encoded string to pass to a classic ASP page on my server. But the problem I can't seem to find an answer to is how to process this data so I can save it someplace on my server.

So with this snippet of code on my HTML page, I pull the canvas data (I pulled this from another post here at StackOverflow):

```
var dataURL = renderedCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");    
dataURL = dataURL.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');

var areturn = $.ajax({
  url: "http://127.0.0.1/mySite/saveImage.asp",
  type: "POST",
  data: '{ "imageData" : "' + dataURL + '" }',
  dataType: "json",
  beforeSend: function(x) {
      x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
  }
}).done(function(result) {
    console.log("Success Done!\n" + result);
}).always(function(data) {
    console.log("Always:\n" + data.responseText);
});
```

But I'm unclear now what to do with the data once I'm on the server side... I can pull the Request.Form element, but I can't seem to find a good way to either base64 decode it, or even output it as a binary file... I guess I've heard that classic ASP isn't any good at doing base64 decoding, and in another test I did find a function that did the base64 decode, but I couldn't tell if it really worked, but it did take a long time to run.
I also found this link here: [base64 image decoder for ASP classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920416/base64-image-decoder-for-asp-classic), but I guess this is a 32bit component that Microsoft doesn't recommend using... I guess I'm looking to the community here for suggestions on saving out an html5 canvas image onto the server.

Comment: Future note: the line `dataURL = dataURL.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');` was required to get Kul-Tigin's answer to work.

Answer (score 5):

You could use an XML element specifying `bin.base64` data type that created through a `DomDocument` instance to encoding / decoding Base64 data. 
Then you can save obtained binary to disk using a `Stream` object. 
Both of these libraries are 64 bit supported. Assuming the content you sent will be available in a Request collection (classic post methods without json etc.) on the server-side, following code solves the problem or at worst I'm sure that gives you insight.

**saveImage.asp**

```vb
Function Base64Data2Stream(sData)
    Set Base64Data2Stream = Server.CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")
        Base64Data2Stream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
        Base64Data2Stream.Open
    With Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument.6.0").createElement("b64")
        .dataType = "bin.base64"
        .text = sData
        Base64Data2Stream.Write .nodeTypedValue 'write bytes of decoded base64 to stream
        Base64Data2Stream.Position = 0
    End With
End Function

Dim CanvasStream
Set CanvasStream = Base64Data2Stream(Request.Form("imageData"))

'Write binary to Response Stream
'Response.BinaryWrite CanvasStream.Read

'Write binary to File
CanvasStream.SaveToFile Server.Mappath("imgFileFromCanvas.png"), 2 'adSaveCreateOverWrite
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for answering. I must admit I'm not quite sure how to implement your suggestion. I can understand your code for saving the image, but I'm not quite sure how to generate the xml element... My front end app that generates the image object I want is currently just an html file with JQuery, but I could make it into a classic ASP page also if it affords me additional functionality.

Comment: @dchin hey, did you ever implement this?  I'd be curious to see how exactly you used it.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply to this, sadly no, I never got this to work... I ended up doing a work around for the entire application I was working on.

Answer (score 0):

just thought I'd share a solution to this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    getBase64FromImageUrl('test5px.png');

            function getBase64FromImageUrl(URL) {
                var img = new Image();
                img.src = URL;
                img.onload = function () {          
                var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                canvas.width =this.width;
                canvas.height =this.height;         
                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);          
                var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");            
                //alert(  dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, ""));
                saveImageData(dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, ""));
                }
            }

            function saveImageData (image_data) {
                $.post("saveImage.asp",
                {imageData:image_data,submit:true})
                .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
                    {
                    alert(data);             
                    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                {
                    alert(textStatus);
                });
 });
```

in html

```
<img id="test" src="http://someDomain.com/img/test5px.png">
```

I was actually getting the image data as a snapshot from a webcam canvas.toDataURL, but it works for  just an img tag on a page as well

In saveImage.asp

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<% Option Explicit %>
<%

response.write(request("imageData"))

Function Base64Data2Stream(sData)
    Set Base64Data2Stream = Server.CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")
        Base64Data2Stream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
        Base64Data2Stream.Open
    With Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument.6.0").createElement("b64")
        .dataType = "bin.base64"
        .text = sData
        Base64Data2Stream.Write .nodeTypedValue 'write bytes of decoded base64 to stream
        Base64Data2Stream.Position = 0
    End With
End Function

Dim CanvasStream
Set CanvasStream = Base64Data2Stream(Request.Form("imageData"))

'Write binary to Response Stream
'Response.BinaryWrite CanvasStream.Read

'Write binary to File
CanvasStream.SaveToFile Server.Mappath("userImages/" & request("imageName")), 2                    'adSaveCreateOverWrite
%>
```

Comment: Thanks David for sharing your solution. It's been a while since I looked at this topic and I'll give it a try shortly. Part of the problem I was facing wasn't so much getting the base64 data from the canvas, but doing something with it on the ASP end to turn in back into an actual binary image to save on disk on the server. What does your saveImage.asp do with the image data?

Answer (score 0):

my answer is based on the first answer, with some modifications that made it actually work:
first, in the client side we use the following function:

```
        function onSave(){
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "saveSignature.asp",
          data: { 
             imgBase64: document.getElementById("eSignatureBoard").toDataURL(),
          }
        })
        .fail(function(oErr,sErr1,sErr2) {
            alert ("err - "+sErr1+"  "+sErr2);
        })    
        .done(function(){
            alert ("done");
        });   
    }
```

and in the asp server side we use the following code:

```
dim sImg
sImg=request.form("imgBase64")
sImg = replace(sImg,"data:image/png;base64,", "")
sImg = replace(sImg," ", "+")

Set oStream = Server.CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")
oStream.Type = 1 
oStream.Open
With Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument.6.0").createElement("b64")
    .dataType = "bin.base64"
    .text = sImg
    oStream.Write .nodeTypedValue 'write bytes of decoded base64 to stream
End With
oStream.SaveToFile Server.Mappath ("./tmp_08221_1.png"), 2
oStream.close()
set oStream = nothing
```